# AWS CLI S3 cp Not Recognizing Quoted Source and Target in Shell Script

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

New to shell scripting.  Trying to use shell script on RHEL 6.9 linux server to upload a file with whitespace in filename to AWS S3 with aws cli.  I have tried single and double quotes and have been reading aws cli links like http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html

Here is a simple version of my script with the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
profile=" --profile XXXXXXX"
sourcefile=" '/home/my_login/data/batch4/Test File (1).zip'"
targetobject=" 's3://my-bucket/TestFolder/batch4/Test File (1).zip'"
service=" s3"
action=" cp"
encrypt=" --sse"
func="aws"
awsstring=$func$profile$service$action$sourcefile$targetobject$encrypt
echo $awsstring
$awsstring
```

When I run I get:

```
$ ./s3copy.sh
aws --profile XXXXXXX s3 cp '/home/my_login/data/batch4/Test File (1).zip' 's3://my-bucket/TestFolder/batch4/Test File (1).zip' --sse

Unknown options: (1).zip','s3://my-bucket/TestFolder/batch4/Test,File,(1).zip'
```

When I execute the $awsstring value from command line, it works:

```
$ aws --profile XXXXXXX s3 cp '/home/my_login/data/batch4/Test File (1).zip' 's3://my-bucket/TestFolder/batch4/Test File (1).zip' --sse
upload: data/batch4/Test File (1).zip to s3://my-bucket/TestFolder/batch4/Test File (1).zip
```

aws cli does not seem to recognize the quotes in the shell script.  I need to quote the file names in my script, because I have white space in them.
Question: Why does the string execute correctly from the command line, but not from within the shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval $awsstring`. I faced similar issue. You can look at my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111888/2396539

On second thought having space in file name is not desirable and if you can control it , avoid it in the 1st place.

Comment: your "eval" solved it - thank-you!  yeah - my requirement is to use existing filenames with whitespace; will see how it goes